# Verify that camera calibration is still valid

Tags: matlab, opencv, camera, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

How do you determine that the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters you have calculated for a camera at time X are still valid at time Y?

My idea would be

1. to use a known calibration object (a chessboard) and place it in the camera's field of view at time Y.
2. Calculate the chessboard corner points in the camera's image (at time Y).
3. Define one of the chessboard corner points as world origin and calculate the world coordinates of all remaining chessboard corners based on that origin.
4. Relate the coordinates of 3. with the camera coordinate system.
5. Use the parameters calculated at time X to calculate the image points of the points from 4.
6. Calculate distances between points from 2. with points from 5.

Is that a clever way to go about it? I'd eventually like to implement it in MATLAB and later possibly openCV. I think I'd know how to do steps 1)-2) and step 6). Maybe someone can give a rough implementation for steps 2)-5). Especially I'd be unsure how to relate the "chessboard-world-coordinate-system" with the "camera-world-coordinate-system", which I believe I would have to do.

Thanks!

Comment: The whole thing sounds about right. Basically what you are saying is that you will re-calibrate the camera and check if the new calibration is more or less the same as the old one. However, I a single camera system, the "only thing" that would change the calibration is either a)Change in the focus of the camera b)change the location of the camera. If the camera is "untouched" then there is no need of re-calibration.

Comment: Well, I was hoping a whole "re-calibration" could be avoided and a verification step could be achieved more easily (e.g. with less images). Yes, the reason for the verification step is, that the camera might be moved slightly and I want to know if the calibration is still valid after that movement.

Comment: Depends on your desired accuracy, but in general, you'd need re-calibration when moved. A good way would be I guess to detect all corners of the chessboard first. Then pick 4 adjacent ones (in a corner better, so the error propagates more) and then estimate with the rest of the points with your parameters. You can get the error between the seen and estimated.

Comment: This sounds a lot like what I wrote, I believe. You however pick for adjacent points and I only took one. Why 4 (and why adjacent ones)?

Comment: If you want to "estimate" points on a plane, you need to know in which plane. Thus 4 (only 3 needed actually) points. Then, using the calibration parameters you estimate points in the plane formed by those points at distance of chessboard square length. The further the points, the bigger the error (try undistorting an image and computing the differencens in adjacent pixels, almost none!).  Thus, better to take points in some corner and let the error be the biggest possible (else it can be 0.001, even in uncalibrated stuff)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single camera you can easily follow the steps from this article:
[Evaluating the Accuracy of Single Camera Calibration](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/evaluating-the-accuracy-of-single-camera-calibration.html)

For achieving step 2, you can easily use `detectCheckerboardPoints` function from MATLAB.

```
 [imagePoints, boardSize, imagesUsed] = detectCheckerboardPoints(imageFileNames);
```

Assuming that you are talking about stereo-cameras, for stereo pairs, `imagePoints(:,:,:,1)` are the points from the first set of images, and `imagePoints(:,:,:,2)` are the points from the second set of images. The output contains `M` number of `[x y]` coordinates. Each coordinate represents a point where square corners are detected on the checkerboard. The number of points the function returns depends on the value of `boardSize`, which indicates the number of squares detected. The function detects the points with sub-pixel accuracy.

As you can see in the following image the points are estimated relative to the first point that covers your third step.

[image]

[The image is from [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectcheckerboardpoints.html) at MATHWORKS.]

You can consider point 1 as the origin of your coordinate system (0,0). The directions of the axes are shown on the image and you know the distance between each point (in the world coordinate), so it is just the matter of depth estimation.

To find a transformation matrix between the points in the world CS and the points in the camera CS, you should collect a set of points and perform an [SVD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html) to estimate the transformation matrix.

**But,**

I would estimate the parameters of the camera and compare them with the initial parameters at time `X`. This is easier, if you have saved the images that were used when calibrating the camera at time `X`. By repeating the calibrating process using those images you should get very similar results, if the camera calibration is still valid.

**Edit:** Why you need the set of images used in the calibration process at time `X`?

You have a set of images to do the calibrations for the first time, right? To recalibrate the camera you need to use a new set of images. But for checking the previous calibration, you can use the previous images. If the parameters of the camera are changes, there would be an error between the re-estimation and the first estimation. This can be used for evaluating the validity of the calibration not for recalibrating the camera.

Comment: Hey! Yeah, I am aware of that function, which is also why omitted step 2). I am not so sure however how that also covers my third step, if you'd elaborate on that, that would be great! I think step three is more a question of the function "generateCheckerboardPoints" actually.

Comment: After your first edit: So you are saying to to relate world CS with camera CS I need to perform an SVD, which would mean I would need a set of points to do so, right? Not sure if I understand the elaboration of the alternative solution. If I get you right, you would simply recalibrate at time Y and compare the calculated parameters with the ones obtained at time X. What would I need the images from X for then?